# How can I make a subclass access private fields from the superclass in javascript?

Tags: javascript, extends, es6-class, private-members, weakmap

I am trying to make a stack and queue classes, but I cant make the data field private without not being able to use inheritance.
I get an Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#data' must be declared in an enclosing class error every time I try.
how can I have the subclasses inherit the private field? code below:

```js
class Datalist {
  #data
  constructor() {
    this.#data = Array.from(arguments)
    return this.#data
  }
  valueOf() {
    return this.#data
  }
  get size() {
    return this.#data.length
  }
  peek() {
    if (this.size > 0) {
      return this.#data[0]
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
}

class Queue extends Datalist {
  constructor() {
    super(arguments)
  }
  enqueue() {
    this.#data = this.#data.concat(arguments)
  }
  dequeue() {
    return this.#data.shift()
  }
}
class Stack extends Datalist {
  constructor() {
    super(arguments)
    this.#data = this.#data.reverse()
  }
  push() {
    this.#data = this.#data.splice(0, 0, Array.from(...arguments).reverse)
  }
  pop() {
    return this.#data.shift()
  }
}
```

Comment: Subclasses inherit private fields but cannot access them directly, so `this.#data` in a subclass won't work.

Comment: In this specific case you could use `valueOf()`, like `return this.valueOf().shift();`, but generally there is no "protected" inheritance in JavaScript at the moment. Of course in this particular case you could just use the built-in `push()` and `pop()` functions anyway.

Comment: Simply don't use private fields for this.

Comment: @DevinMyers ... Regarding the so far sole answer / approach are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround which keeps the approach of extended classes and prototypal methods together with private fields and protected data could be based on [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) because one can take advantage of working with a single shared reference for each instantiation regardless of the actual inheritance.

```js
const privateListLookup = new WeakMap;

const getPrivateList = reference =>
  privateListLookup.get(reference);

const getClone = value =>
  (typeof structuredClone === 'function')
    ? structuredClone(value)
    : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));

// const getCopy = value => [...value];


class DataList {
  constructor(...list) {
    // enable shared privacy via an instance's
    // `this` reference and a weak map.
    privateListLookup.set(this, list);
  }
  valueOf() {
    // ensure data protection by not exposing
    // the private `list` reference directly.
    return getClone(getPrivateList(this));

    // // make a decision, clone or shallow copy.
    // return getCopy(getPrivateList(this));
  }
  toString() {
    return String(getPrivateList(this));
  }
  // toJSON() {
  //   return JSON.stringify(getPrivateList(this));
  // }
  get size() {
    return getPrivateList(this).length;
  }
  peek() {
    return (this.size > 0)
      // ? getPrivateList(this).at(0)
      ? getPrivateList(this)[0]
      : null;
  }
}


class Queue extends DataList {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
  enqueue(...args) {
    getPrivateList(this).push(...args);
  }
  dequeue() {
    return getPrivateList(this).shift();
  }
}

class Stack extends DataList {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    getPrivateList(this).reverse();
  }
  push(...args) {
    getPrivateList(this).push(...args);
  }
  pop() {
    return getPrivateList(this).pop();
  }
}


const queue = new Queue(...['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']);
const stack = new Stack('jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog');

console.log({
  queue: queue.valueOf(),
  stack: stack.valueOf(),
});
console.log({
  queue: queue.toString(),
  stack: stack.toString(),
});

console.log(
  'queue.enqueue(stack.pop()) ...'
);
queue.enqueue(stack.pop());

console.log({
  queue: queue.toString(),
  stack: stack.toString(),
});

console.log(
  'queue.enqueue(stack.pop(), stack.pop()) ...'
);
queue.enqueue(stack.pop(), stack.pop());

console.log({
  queue: queue.toString(),
  stack: stack.toString(),
});

console.log(
  'stack.peek() ...', stack.peek()
)
console.log(
  'stack.push(queue.dequeue(), queue.dequeue()) ...'
);
stack.push(queue.dequeue(), queue.dequeue());

console.log({
  queue: queue.toString(),
  stack: stack.toString(),
});
console.log({
  queue: queue.valueOf(),
  stack: stack.valueOf(),
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```